# Calling colorbox() for links in ajax-loaded content in tabs()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, colorbox, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI tabs() to load ajax content into the page.
some of this content has links to modal windows that should be opening via `colorbox()` but i cant get them to launch properly.

Can someone give me some directions?
Do i need to include the colorbox library in the content loaded via ajax? I assume it should suffice that its in the parent page, and i just call colorbox again after the content has loaded, but i casnt get it to work.

This is what i have (which does nothing)...:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs().bind('tabsload',function(event, ui){
    //alert('The tab is loaded. What now?');
    $("#tabs .iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"65%", height:"80%"});
});
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code. Can you create a Fiddle? I'm curious about why your selector is `#tabs .iframe`. Are you loading your ajax content into an iFrame inside each tab?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've presented here; and no, you don't need to include the library via ajax -- including it n the parent page is sufficient. Check that it is loaded properly (maybe you mis-specified the path?) by calling `console.log(!!$.colorbox)` or `alert(!!$.colorbox)` . If you verify that it is  loaded properly, we'll need to see your HTML to help figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Also ensure that the tabs are loading: try `$( "#tabs" ).tabs().bind('tabsload',function(){alert('loaded');})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me so far. I've thrown together a simple fiddle that demonstrates this functionality. I used the `activate` event instead of `load`, because the latter wasn't working (although that may be because I wasn't loading my tabs via AJAX). Either way, `activate` should work for you, too:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        $("#tabs .colorbox").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"65%", height:"80%"});
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g27szcop/1/

You shouldn't need to include the colorbox library in the AJAX content, unless you're doing something weird like creating an iFrame inside each tab and then loading the content into *that*. If you are able to post more of your code, I can update my fiddle with additional advice.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the reply. I tried your code, but it didnt seem to make any difference. I tried setting up a jsfiddle, but couldn't work out how to make a `echo/html` in the context of tabs. here is a basic setup (does not fucntion, ajax-wise), just so that you can see the structure.  http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/0uwnd5q1/  There is no iframe in the tabs - some of the tab links sinply make ajax calls, and the html that is returned, is displayed in the form of a tab, as in http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax (content via ajax example)

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. I'm not sure why it's not working for you. Can you post more of your code? It must be a subtle error I'm not seeing. (Is this page online anywhere?)

Comment: Weird, the demo I setup, works!  http://bit.ly/1D4djS2   
I will look at it again in the morning (2Am here) - thanks again

Comment: I just played with everything again. I don't know how, but it seems to work now. I will award you the points when its released - thank you.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help (if even a little). In your demo, you've got multiple calls to `.colorbox()` - probably isn't causing problems, but it could cause some confusion to anyone reading the source. I'd also recommend playing with binding to `load` vs. `activate`. (In your demo, I don't _think_ the link on the 3rd tab will be bound by the `load` event because it's static. I could be wrong, however.) Glad you got it working!

Comment: I figured i needed 2 calls to `colorbox` - one for the `onload`, and the 2nd, for after the ajax content is loaded - and then I bind the function again on the new content. Is this incorrect?  Thanks!

Comment: It's not incorrect necessarily, but I think it's redundant. You should be able to get away without that first call.